# Boundary error events do not seem to work in Processmaker 4

Tags: processmaker

I have tried defining a process like in the image:
[image]

My understanding was that boundary error events would triguer if an error ocurs in the task they are binded to. In this case, tascs A and B are scripts that make an HTTP request. When for some reason the service they call is not available, the code throws an exception (either timeout of empty response). If I do not use the boundary error events, the process simply fails and reports an error.
The idea behind this workflow was that if there was an error of this sort, using the boundary error event, I would direct flow of the process to a task assigned to the administrator. Then the administrator could check if the services were running, and once the error is corrected, could proceed with the proces by executing those tasks again.
Unfortunately, when I use the boundary error event, instead of the process failing as before, it just stays in "in progress" status, but no task gets assigned to the administrator.
Am I using the boundary error events wrong? Or are they simply not working in Processmaker 4?
Definitely the boundary error event is catching the error for some reason, because the task is not failin, but it is not directing the flow to the form that I designed and therefore can not continue with the process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that boundary error events work. The issue seem to be related with the assignment that the task had. I assigned it to an "Administrators" group and it didn't work. But when I assign it directly to the Admin user, it worked perfectly.